# Which LDAP JNDI provider pool settings are system properties, and which are environment properties?

Tags: ldap, jndi, connection-pooling

Java's JNDI LDAP provider supports connection pooling, but some of the parameters are system properties set on a per-JVM level on the Java command line. Others are included in the environmental properties on the `InitialLdapContext` level.

What options are available? Which are system properties and which are environmental properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [LDAP Naming Service Provider for the Java Naming and Directory Interface™ (JNDI guide)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-ldap.html) has a table of system properties, but doesn't lay out the environmental ones as clearly.

System properties (JVM-wide):

- `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.authentication`
- `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug`
- `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.initsize`
- `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.maxsize`
- `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.prefsize`
- `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol`
- `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout`

Environment properties specified when creating context:

- `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool`
- `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout`
- `com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout`
- `com.sun.jndi.ldap.netscape.schemaBugs`
- `com.sun.jndi.ldap.trace.ber`